# React-bootstrap hamburger menu not appearing when shrinking page size

Tags: navbar, react-bootstrap

I am attempting to have a hamburger menu appear on my navbar when the page shrinks.

```
    return (
      <div id="horizontalNavbar" className={`${styles.menuHorizontal}`}>
        <nav className='a-header-wrapper justify-content-between' }>
          <div className='a-brand-container position-relative w-100'>
            <span className='font-weight-bold'>Test</span>
                <Navbar.Collapse className={styles.navbarCollapse}>
                  <Nav className={styles.navbarNav}>
                    {(this.props.items || []).map((item, index) => this.createHorizontalMenuItem(item, index))}
                  </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    )
```

Currently when I resize the page nothing happens.
I have tested and confirmed that

```
{(this.props.items || []).map((item, index) => this.createHorizontalMenuItem(item, index))}
```

is returning elements to rendered in the Hamburger menu. But the actual hamburger is not appearing

Answer (score 0):

Try to add toggle button and id to Navbar.Collapse:

```
<Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
<Navbar.Collapse className={styles.navbarCollapse} id="basic-navbar-nav">
    <Nav className={styles.navbarNav}>
                {(this.props.items || []).map((item, index) => this.createHorizontalMenuItem(item, index))}
    </Nav>
</Navbar.Collapse>
```